# Hide parameter panel after submit devexpress

Tags: c#, parameters, devexpress, xtrareport

I am working with devexpress xtrareports to preview reports for my windows forms application. i have 2 parameters in the report and so when the preview window shows up the parameter panel is open, so the end user can select the parameters and click  on submit.
I want to close the parameter panel after the end user has pressed submit. 
I have researched on how to do this and i came across this solution [this solution on the devexpress site](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q439200/how-to-hide-the-parameter-panel-after-submitting-parameter-values)

but when i implement it in my project it gives a null reference error

the code code i got from the site is below

```
    private void XtraReport1_ParametersRequestSubmit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.ParametersRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        ReportPrintTool tool = ((XtraReport1)sender).ReportPrintTool as ReportPrintTool;
        if (tool != null)
        {
            PrintControl control = tool.PreviewForm.PrintControl;

            foreach (DockPanel panel in control.DockManager.Panels)
                if (panel.Text == PreviewLocalizer.GetString(PreviewStringId.ParametersRequest_Caption))
                {
                    control.DockManager.RemovePanel(panel);
                    break;
                }

            this.RequestParameters = false;
        }

    }
```

it crashes on the foreach line because the dockmanager is null. Can i get some help on hiding the parameters panel after the submit button is clicked in a devexpress reportprinttool.

If i check whether it is null first before running the foreach loop then it simply does not run and the parameter panel stays. 
 I am using devexpress version 18.1. Visual studio 2017 enterprise on a windows 10 operating system. and the language is c#

Comment: Did you download the zip file mentioned at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q439200/how-to-hide-the-parameter-panel-after-submitting-parameter-values and have a look at how it is setting up the dock manager?

Comment: Yes i downloaded the zip file. the code in the report file ParametersRequestSubmit event is exactly as i have shown in my question. but when i run that code it crashes and gives an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: In which line the exception has thrown? Your setup looks already on the right track but seem something which you're not mentioned here went wrong.

Comment: foreach (DockPanel panel in control.DockManager.Panels) <= this line

Comment: in the foreach loop line it says control.DockManager is null